# how to access sql server 2008 express database using clickonce

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, clickonce, setup-deployment

I have created a desktop application with visual studio 2012 and Sql Server 2008 R2 and want to deploy the application on client machine.I am using clickonce technique to deploy the application.How should I deploy the database on client machine or what connection string should be mentioned during publishing the application.By default the connection string is :

```
Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

When I create a clickonce application 3 files get created

1. setup.exe
2. ABC.Application
3. Folder named Application files

When I click on **setup.exe** necessary setup get installed but when i try to access the database from installed application it throws error :

> *Unhandled exception has occured in your application.A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server) *

Comment: You have to use an PC/Server-Name or an IP-Address in your `Data Source`. Means you have to get rid of the **Point** as DataSource. Otherwise you have to make sure, all clients have an SQL-Express running and your desired Database exists

Comment: Tried  PC/Server-Name or an IP-Address still no success

Comment: Make sure, your Firewall isnt blocking anything, Users have rights and rquired services are **all** up running. There are many possibilities where something can go wrong

Comment: Firewall is disabled